# Ajax paged list pass object to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, pagedlist

I am working on some advanced searching functionality and I have run into a roadblock.  I would like to use AJAX for my search results and use the PagedList additons to handle paging.  I have an AdvancedSearchResults action which takes a search filters class and the current page.  The issue is how can I pass the search Filters class into this action correctly.  I am sure something I am doing just isnt organized correctly as I would think this would be fairly common.  I would really appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.

Controller Action:

```
  public ActionResult AdvancedSearchResults(AdvancedSearchFilters searchFilters, int ? page)
  {
      //DO STUFF

      return PartialView("_SearchResults", results);
  }
```

AdvancedSearchResults Filters:

```
public class AdvancedSearchFilters
{
   public string SearchText { get; set; }
   public List<string> SelectedTableTypes { get; set; }
   public List<Guid> SelectedGenreIds { get; set; }
   public List<Guid> SelectedPlatformIds { get; set; }
   public int YearMax { get; set; }
   public int YearMin { get; set; }
   public int RatingMin { get; set; }
   public int RatingMax { get; set; }
}
```

Search Results Partial View:

```
    @model List<SearchResultItem>

@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc

<!-- 15 Per Page -->
<h2>Search Results</h2>
@if (ViewBag.OnePageOfSearchItems.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="pagination">
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfSearchItems, page => Url.Action("AdvancedSearchResults", "Search", new { searchFilters = ViewBag.AdvancedSearchFilters, page = page }), 
                              PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime, "#main-results"))
    </div>
    foreach (var searchResultItem in Model)
    {
        <a href="@Url.Action(searchResultItem.ResultType, searchResultItem.ResultType, new { id = searchResultItem.ResultId })" class="result">
            @if (searchResultItem.ProfileImageLocation != null)
            {
                <img src="@searchResultItem.ProfileImageLocation" alt="@searchResultItem.ResultName" />
            }
            <div class="result-info">
                <h3>@searchResultItem.ResultName</h3>
                <p>@searchResultItem.DisplayText</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    }
    <div class="pagination">
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfSearchItems, page => Url.Action("AdvancedSearchResults", "Search", new { searchFilters = ViewBag.AdvancedSearchFilters , page = page }), 
                              PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime, "#main-results"))
    </div>
}
else
{
    <span>No Matches.</span>
}
```

Comment: What are you using to fetch your data? (for exmaple Entity framework, NHibernate, datasets?)

Comment: I am using entity framework, but since the search can retrieve multiple types of data I had to make a more generic model to store it all in.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the data to action method in the form of json. Try the below code which pass the json object to action method.

```
//// construct your json object.
var jsonObj = '{"SelectedTableTypes" : [{"1","2"}]}';


var postData = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);


$.ajax(
   {
       url: // your URL with Action name AdvancedSearchResults,
       data: postData,
       cache: false,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {

       },
       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                alert(xhr.status);
                                alert(thrownError);
       }
   });
```